# GTK FileChooser causes crashes in several programs

Tags: firefox, manjaro, gtk, libreoffice, glib

I have repeatedly encountered a problem with several programs that use open/save file dialogues.

Upon initiating these by trying to open or to save a file, the program freezes for about 10 seconds and then crashes. With `libreoffice` for example, I get the following error message when started from terminal:

```
Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

(soffice:1466): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 19:11:38.289: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' does not contain a key named 'show-type-column'


Fatal exception: Signal 5
Stack:
```

A stack trace follows.

I have read about a similar problem on [AskUbuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164570/broken-schema-org-gtk-settings-filechooser#897299), but the solution (multiple versions of `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml`) does not apply to me.

The file seems to have the appropriate contents (to me). Excerpt about the key mentioned in the error:

```
<key name='show-type-column' type='b'>
  <default>true</default>
  <summary>Show file types</summary>
  <description>
Controls whether the file chooser shows a column with file types.
  </description>
</key>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: As a workaround, it is possible to change the desktop theme to avoid the problem. (Should I post this as an answer?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced this bug in 1.01 AppImage of Inkscape.

Mike Nealy gives an explanation and workaround in a bug report [here](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1616)

I've copied his workaround below:

> Simply updating the schema to contain show-type-column isn't enough.

> Downloading the newer schema file from
> https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/c925221aa804aec344bdfec148a17d23299b6c59/gtk/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml
> and installing it in
> /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml,
> running "glib-compile-schemas ." in that directory and using Alt-F2 r
> to restart gnome-shell seems to resolve the issue with Inkscape 1.0.1.

Comment: If I run `inkscape` from `snap`, it is unfortunately still crashing after doing this...

Comment: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/2495 `sudo snap remove inkscape && sudo snap install inkscape`

Answer (score 4):

For Inkscape 1.1 from snap you have to `sudo snap remove inkscape && sudo snap install inkscape` https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/2495

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the xfce4-theme I was using is faulty as of now, so I switched to another one as a workaround. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Removing snap and installing from apt fixed the issue for me.